# Second printf is not coming up and I am unsure why

Tags: c

This is my code. The second `printf` and `getchar` does not pop up after hitting enter for the first `scanf`. I am unsure why the second `printf` and `getchar` are not working and what the fix would be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int choice;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    int n;
    n = 1;
    int p;
    char message[1000];
    printf("Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: ");
    scanf("%i\n", choice);
    printf("\nType your message: ");
    message[p] = getchar();

    for (i = 1; (i < 1000 && message[p] != '\0');) {
        message[p] = message[p] + n;
        n + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; (i < 1000 && message[p] != '\0');) {
        message[p] = message[p] - n;
        n + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag c questions with c++, they're different languages. Also, please format your code.

Comment: 1) enable all warnings.2) `scanf("%i\n", choice);` --> `scanf("%i", &choice);`

Comment: @Sbroberg Review the value of `p` on  `message[p] = getchar();`

Comment: Also review the man page for "getchar()" examining what it does...

Comment: regarding; `message[p] = getchar();`  the index 'p' is not initialized to a known value.  Therefore it is unknown where that returned value from `getchar()` is being place.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%i\n", choice);`  the variable `choice` is being 'set' but never 'used'  and the posted code is never verifying that that entered value is 1 or 2

Comment: regarding: `message[p] = getchar();`   This inputs a single 'int', not a whole message.  Suggest: `fgets( message, sizeof( message ), stdin );`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 1; (i < 1000 && message[p] != '\0');) {
        message[p] = message[p] + n;
        n + 1;
    }`  this iterates over the whole input `message` contents, copying each successive char into (wherever) the index 'p' off of `message`.  This has no effect on the contents of `message[]` (unless 'p' happens to contain a value less than the length of `message[]`.  What are you trying to perform with this code block?   ALSO. the variable 'i' is never being incremented, so will be <1000 forever, so the loop will continue, forever

Answer (score 0):

> Your encription method works for encription and decription.  This compiles and takes in a string including spaces modifies it and prints it out.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()  {
       int choice;
       char temp;
       int i = 0;
       int n = 1;
       int p, b;
       char message[1000];
       char endmessage[1000];
       printf("Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: ");

       scanf("%i", &choice); // change as per comment above
       scanf("%c", &temp); /* temp statement to clear buffer otherwise a second character has to be typed before the next print statement is executed */
       printf("Type your message: "); //prompt added for user clarity
       scanf("%[^\n]", message);  /* this scanf line allows for spaces in the message */
       printf("\nmessage typed is:  %s \n", message);
       p = (sizeof( message) + 1);  /* strings need to have an ending '\0'
       message[p] = '\0';
       if (choice == 1) {
           for (i = 0; (i < 1000 && message[i] != '\0');) {
               endmessage[i] = (message[i] + n);
               i +=1;
           }
           b = (sizeof( endmessage)); // replace encripted \0 with '\0'
           endmessage[b] = putchar('\0');
           printf("\nYour message encripted is: %s\n\n", endmessage);        
       }
       if (choice == 2) {
           for (i = 0; (i < 1000 && message[i] != '\0');) {
               endmessage[i] = message[i] - n;
               i += 1;
           }
           b = (sizeof(endmessage) -2); // replace decripted \0 with '\0'
           endmessage[b] = putchar('\0');
           printf("\nYour message decripted is: %s\n\n", endmessage);

       }

   }
```

Comment: Your unexplained answer starts off with a quote-formatted paragraph. Where are you quoting from?

Comment: Yunnosch Thank you for your clarification the why is the "scanf("%c", &temp); // temp statement to clear buffer" that is missing in the original code so not clearing the buffer was one of the problems.  Which is the 'quote formatted paragraph'?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer, explain all the problems, explain all the solutions. As text. Inside the answer. Try not to use confusing formatting (use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ).